# choose option is not working

Tags: xslt-1.0

My build script creates 4 different names of Build

```
STP_13_00_00_00_RC01
STPMON_13_00_00_00_RC01
STPWEB_13_00_00_00_RC01
STPPRODUCTS_13_00_00_00_RC01
```

so I want when script create the build with name `**STP_13_00_00_00_RC01**` it should create the folder and then copy the tar file in that folder and after that it should make one more folder whereas if the build name starts with other name STPMON,STPWEB.STPPRODUCTS then it should just create the folder and copy the tar file in that folder So I used the below condidtion.But for all builds it goes into otherwise condition either the build is created with STP

```
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="gzip">
  <xsl:attribute name="destfile"
    >${archive.base}/${gbl.dist.label}.tar.gz</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="src"
    >${archive.base}/${gbl.dist.label}.tar</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains(node,'STP')">
    <xsl:element name="mkdir">
      <xsl:attribute name="dir"
        >/mnt/projects/autoblds_dev_build/blds_dev_stp2build/${gbl.dist.label}</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="copy">
      <xsl:attribute name="file">${archive.base}/${gbl.dist.label}.tar.gz</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="todir"
        >/mnt/projects/autoblds_dev_build/blds_dev_stp2build/${gbl.dist.label}/</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="overwrite">no</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="mkdir">
      <xsl:attribute name="dir"
        >/mnt/projects/autoblds_dev_build/blds_dev_stp2build/${soa.release.version}</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:element name="mkdir">
      <xsl:attribute name="dir"
        >/mnt/projects/autoblds_dev_build/blds_dev_stp2build/${gbl.dist.label}_Test</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="copy">
      <xsl:attribute name="file"
         >${archive.base}/${gbl.dist.label}.tar.gz</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="todir"
         >/mnt/projects/autoblds_dev_build/blds_dev_stp2build/${gbl.dist.label}_Test/</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="overwrite">no</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your choose instruction branches on the condition

```
contains(node,'STP')
```

This has at least one problem, and probably two.

Your description of the problem says you want to behave one way for the build named `STP_13_00_00_00_RC01`, and differently for the builds whose names begin with `STPMON`, `STPWEB`, or  `STPPRODUCTS`.  But all of those build names contain the string 'STP', so your test condition does nothing to distinguish among them.  In other words, your code isn't going to do what you want because you haven't said what you mean.

You say the test is never succeeding (the stylesheet is always taking the `otherwise` branch).  That suggests that the expression `node` is not evaluating to the string you seem to be expecting, nor to a document node that could be coerced to the string you are expecting.  Likely causes include:

- Your XML has no element named `node`.
- Your XML has an element named `node`, but it's not a child of the context node for the template from which your code is quoted.
- Your XML has an element named `node`, which is a child of the context node, but its string value is not the name of the build.

Any of these is possible, but if I had to guess, I'd guess it is the first of these.